# Find Long/Lat inside of polygon with MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, gps, mapping, spatial

I have a `locations` table that has many rows of locations and data. There are 2 columns inside of that - Longitude and Latitude. I want to find records from that table that are found in a defined map polygon area.

I have a second table that I just created based on some tutorials called `polyThing` which has my defined boundary...

```
CREATE TABLE polyThing
    (
        `ID` int auto_increment primary key,
        `boundary` polygon not null,
            `testarea` varchar(200) NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO polyThing (boundary, testarea)
        VALUES(
            PolygonFromText(
                'POLYGON(( 
        -114.018522 46.855932 ,
        -113.997591 46.856030 ,
        -113.997447 46.848626 ,
        -114.018161 46.848824 ,
        -114.018522 46.855932 ))'
            ), 'Test Area 1'
        );
```

I want to find records from `locations` that are inside this defined polygon, and I've been trying queries similar to this. I get 0 records no matter what I try.

```
SELECT *
FROM locations
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(
    (SELECT boundary FROM polyThing
    WHERE polyThing.testarea = 'Test Area 1')
, Point(Longitude, Latitude))
```

Here is `locations` table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `LocationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Latitude` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;


INSERT INTO `locations` (`LocationID`, `Location`, `Longitude`, `Latitude`) VALUES
(1, 'In the polygon', '-114.007191', '46.853019'),
(2, 'In the polygon', '-114.003798', '46.851045'),
(3, 'Not in', '-114.016934', '46.866098');
```

Love to get a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `(Longitude, l.Latitude)` are in locations?

**[Sql DEMO:](https://rextester.com/JSLYC95685)**

```
SELECT l.*,  ST_CONTAINS(p.boundary, POINT(l.Longitude, l.Latitude))
FROM locations l
CROSS JOIN polyThing p;
 
SELECT l.*
FROM locations l
JOIN polyThing p
  ON ST_CONTAINS(p.boundary, POINT(l.Longitude, l.Latitude))
 AND p.testarea = 'Test Area 1';
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: Yes, Long/Lat are `locations` I had to make some changes to the SQL..

`SELECT l.*, p.*
 FROM locations l
 JOIN polyThing p
   ON ST_CONTAINS(p.boundary, POINT(l.Longitude, l.Latitude))
  WHERE p.testarea = 'Test Area 1'`

Still returns 0 records? Do you think it might be my boundary definition in `polyThing`?

Comment: `polyThing` table with points is above in the original post. I just added `locations` with long/lat value in that post just now.

Comment: Check Update version