# A SQL query that shows Daily and Total quantity in one table grouped by names. How to do?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I want to combine the daily consumption data with the total consumption (`sum(qty) where...`) in one table, with Name, Daily and Total columns.

This will put the sum of the daily quantities to all cells of the column, and I don't know what to write in the embedded select statement (I just have an idea to loop through the set of names, but that seems complicated):

```
select name, 
       (select sum(qty) from items where date='2017-07-13') as daily,
       sum(qty) as total 
from items 
group by nev with rollup
```

With a JOIN, I can't do the ROLLUP correctly. I have to GROUP BY by names before ROLLUP, so the sum of Total will be on the top, and the Daily won't be rolled up, which seems so awkward.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it easily and elegantly? Thank you.

Comment: `ROLLUP` is to show the total of all the `SUM`, what is your desire result?

Comment: I want to have in each row a person, his daily consumption, and the total consumption, say {Daniel, 4, 140}, {Anne, 0, 30}, {Roger, 3, 100}, {Sum, 7, 270}.

Comment: please provide DDL for your table and data, something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286763/find-long-lat-inside-of-polygon-with-mysql-5-6/44286864#44286864

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
select name, 
   dayofyear(date), 
   year(date),
   sum(qty) 
from items 
group by name, dayofyear(date), year(date) with rollup
```

should produce the daily quantities, the rollup should produce additionally records where the grouping columns will sometimes be NULL, then the corresponding quantity is accumulated for this.

Comment: Hmm, did not get the result I wanted :/

Comment: I assume you want a separate column for the totals, not additional records to extract the totals and semitotals there?

Comment: In that case you could use common table expressions if possible (postgres??) to create something like a temporary table containing the total. joining the group with this total would deliver it there. --- no, I think you could get the total by using a selfjoin (name = name and column2 is null and column3 is null) on the first result by which you can add the total to your result

Comment: well will help if you show us some sample data and what result you want. Otherwise is a guessing game :(