# How to find locations which are within polygon cords using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search the places which are within polygon coordinates.

My polygon cords json array is like this:

```
[{"lat":23.044131034993626,"lng":72.52770534192086},{"lat":23.045493462614736,"lng":72.53060212765695},{"lat":23.04381510777979,"lng":72.53163209591867},{"lat":23.042472408854092,"lng":72.52843490277291}]
```

My database table name is places and its has values like below:

```
id  lat         lng         
1   23.0449391  72.5301363 
2   23.044816   72.529531  
3   23.0439868  72.5291617 
4   23.0440151  72.5291033 
5   23.0441163  72.529624  
6   23.044531   72.52946   
7   23.0449581  72.5301291 
8   23.044081   72.529584  
9   23.0440654  72.5295851 
10  23.0443758  72.529803  
11  23.047929   72.527231    
11  23.0464945  72.5288149
```

So I want the places which are within polygon cords

In the above table first 10 points are in the polygon cords and remaining two are outside of it

I have tried this query but it is not working

```
select id, lat, lng from places 
where st_within(point(lng, lat),  ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((72.52770534192086 23.044131034993626, 72.53060212765695 23.045493462614736, 72.53163209591867 23.04381510777979,72.52843490277291 23.042472408854092))'));
```

So please suggest me mysql select query for this.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect a bit more of an effort from you here, than that you just drop off your requirement.

Comment: Google maps has an API that will let you know if one location is with a polygon of lat/long.

Comment: I want to use mysql query

Comment: _“So please suggest me mysql select query for this.”_ - that is still not a question, not in the way you are supposed to ask here on this site. We are not here to completely do your work for you. _Show us_ what efforts you have made so far to try and solve this - what did your research turn up, what did you try and with what results …

Comment: I have followed this post but I can't get any result : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286763/find-long-lat-inside-of-polygon-with-mysql-5-6/44286864

Comment: Okay, let me add

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if there is a way to do it in MySql, but in PHP you can do that.

if you can retrieve the data from your DB in an array structures such as the following

```
$pol = array(
    array('lat' => 23.034002369168842,'lng' => 72.56034198842099),
    array('lat' => 23.033439580995058,'lng' => 72.56498757443478),
    array('lat' => 23.03146486705749, 'lng' => 72.56323877415707),
    array('lat' => 23.029875201316813,'lng' => 72.55889359555295),
    array('lat' => 23.031682087006978,'lng' => 72.55772415242245),
    array('lat' => 23.032955778756484,'lng' => 72.55875412068417),
    array('lat' => 23.033972748797236,'lng' => 72.56003085217526)
);
```

and your point's coordinates such as

```
$point = array('lat' =>, 23.0337224, 'lng' => 72.5668896);
```

the function which tell you if the point is within the polygon may be something like

```
function is_inside($point, $polygon) {
    if ($polygon[0] != $polygon[count($polygon) - 1])
        $polygon[count($polygon)] = $polygon[0];
    $j = 0;
    $inside = false;
    $x = $point['lat'];
    $y = $poin['lng'];
    $n = count($polygon);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) :
        $j++;
        if ($j == $n)
            $j = 0;
        if ((($polygon[$i]['lng'] < $y) && ($polygon[$j]['lng'] >= $y)) || (($polygon[$j]['lng'] < $y) && ($polygon[$i]['lng'] >= $y))) :
            if ($polygon[$i]['lat'] + ($y - $polygon[$i]['lng']) / ($polygon[$j]['lng'] - $polygon[$i]['lng']) * ($polygon[$j]['lat'] - $polygon[$i]['lat']) < $x)
                $inside = !$inside;
        endif;
    endfor;

    return $inside;
}
```

so you can check if the point is inside just calling the function

```
if(is_inside($point, $polygon)){
     /* do something */
}
```