# How to store polygon coordinates using polygon in the MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update polygon data by using below query, but it's not affecting in the table row.

```
UPDATE tbl_location SET `boundary` = PolygonFromText(
            'POLYGON(( 
    -86.782167 36.162098 ,
    -86.779759 36.161742 ,
    -86.781035 36.163229 ,
    -86.782167 36.163229 ,
    -86.783529 36.162637 ))'
        ) WHERE id='5'
```

My table field name is `boundary` polygon not null

I have used reference link : [Find Long/Lat inside of polygon with MySQL 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286763/find-long-lat-inside-of-polygon-with-mysql-5-6)
But when I try to update exact data from the above link then it's working fine, but it's not affecting when I try with my polygon lat long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polygon has a starting point and also the **same** end point

So it should look like this to work.,
Of course you must see that the "middle points" fit, i only made a working sample

```
UPDATE tbl_location SET `boundary` = PolygonFromText(
        'POLYGON((     
-86.782167 36.163229 ,
-86.781035  36.162098 ,
-86.779759 36.161742 ,
-86.783529 36.162637, 
-86.782167 36.163229 
))'
    ) WHERE ID='1'
```

You don't have a polygon.

you have to use multipoint, to save such information

> ```
> SET @mp = 'MULTIPOINT( -86.7821670 36.1632290,
> -86.7835290 36.1626370,
> -86.7797590 36.1617420,
> -86.7810350 36.1620980)';
> SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromText(@mp));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> | ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromText(@mp))                                                                         |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | MULTIPOINT((-86.782167 36.163229),(-86.783529 36.162637),(-86.779759 36.161742),(-86.781035 36.162098)) |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4f66b0b4edb4f52718f39137fa7e51c5)*

Comment: Again getting problem on below query, I have used same as you mentioned 
UPDATE `tbl_location ` SET boundary = PolygonFromText(
    'POLYGON(( 
    -71.059445 42.359516,
    -71.058314 42.359516,
    -71.058314 42.360648,
    -71.059445 42.360648,
    -71.059445 42.359516))'
) WHERE id = 2

Comment: Ti expand my answer a polygon is a geometrical object that starts at Point A goes over three  different points that are connected and ends at the same point A. Your update doesn't come with that. First think about what shape you wandt a line as in your case isn't defined as a poligon

Comment: [https://www.keene.edu/campus/maps/tool/?coordinates=-86.7821670%2C%2036.1632290%0A-86.7835290%2C%2036.1626370%0A-86.7797590%2C%2036.1617420%0A-86.7810350%2C%2036.1620980%0A-86.7821670%2C%2036.1632290] and [https://www.keene.edu/campus/maps/tool/?coordinates=-71.0594450%2C%2042.3595160%0A-71.0583140%2C%2042.3595160%0A-71.0583140%2C%2042.3606480%0A-71.0594450%2C%2042.3606480%0A-71.0594450%2C%2042.3595160]
Both links are based on the above polygon and close the shape after opening that links, can you please check what I have to do?, I need to store these types of polygon

Comment: i added some sample code for one of the point the rest goes accordingly, but it is better to switch to mysql 8 for that, it is much more spophisticated